# In POS systems is it common practice to put the new record to the top?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview, receipt

In POS systems there is Invoice on to which the items are added. Typically the checkout operator can see this invoice as a DataGridView with items. But I need to know:

1. in POS systems is it a common practice to place the newly added record at the top of the datagrid?
2. When printing a receipt is it common practice to print items on to the receipt in the order of First added top of the receipt and last added last of the receipt rows?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with SEV19957 that the proper way to add new items to the list would be to append those to the bottom and push the other items in the list up.  This is the approach used by [OpenRPOS](http://openrpos.com), an open source point of sale system for restaurants, and it's a fairly standard practice in the industry.

For question #2, I guess it would depend on the type of POS you are implementing.  For restaurants, it makes sense to display items in the same way they were added on the display.  But for something like a grocery store, you may want to consolidate like items, breaking the slip into separate sections and grouping together items from deli, produce, bakery, etc...

I hope that this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I work at a chick fil a and we utilise a pretty nice pos system.
To answer your first question, from the experience I have with our pos system the record gets put at the bottom of the data grid. As new items are added it gets pushed up the list or as you say data grid.

For the second question, referring back to the way the data grid is utilised as i suggested in my first answer, the receipt should display the first item entered at the top and as you look down the list the items become more recent until you reach the bottom which has the final entered item.

Hope this helped, this is my first post on stackoverflow.